# WCF customBinding over HTTPS

Tags: wcf, web-services, custom-binding

I have a situation where i need to sign a soap request w/ a X509 certificate for consumption by a java web service.  Thru the magic of WCF we were able to get the envelope formed properly and all looks great over standard http.  However, once we move to HTTPS (required by client), we start receiving errors "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority" .. We've tried tweaking some settings and changing the target domain to other known HTTPS sites and we still receive the same error.  Below is our client configuration, thanks so much in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding
          name="myCustomBinding"
          closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <textMessageEncoding
                  messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security
            allowInsecureTransport="true"
            authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
            requireDerivedKeys="false"
            keyEntropyMode="ClientEntropy"
            includeTimestamp="false"
            securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
            messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate
              findValue="MyCertName"
              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindByIssuerName"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication
                revocationMode="NoCheck"
                trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint
        address="https://www.SomeUrl.com"
        binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="myCustomBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpCertificateBehavior"
        contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceTest"
        name="untk48_dfSoap">
        <identity>
          <certificateReference findValue="MyCertName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your certificate friendly name match the domain name for https?

Ive had to do in the past to get HTTPS WCF to validate correctly

e.g

Friendly name box1.mycompany.au.net

Domain for request https://box1.mycompany.au.net

Answer (score -1):

Install the certificate on the client and you wont have this issue.
When you install it make sure you install it to the Intermediate Certification Authorities and the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Worked for me.

Comment: It might have worked for you, but that doesn't make installing any old certificate into any of the CA stores the right thing to do.